Accessing a Python Object Instance by using a user-input
im trying to access a class method from a user input. An example would be that i want to get access the method "drive_to(destination)" from the instance "fast_bycicle" of the class "Bicycle". I want to let the user decide which bike to use so my idea kinda looks like this
class Bycicle():
   def __init__(self, color, position)
       self.color = color
       self.position = position
   def drive_to(self, destination)
       self.position = destination


fast_bycicle = Bycicle("red","home")
       


x = input("Please select a bike: ")
x = "fast_bycicle"
y = input("Please select a destination: ")
y = "Hamburg"


x.drive_to(y)

which falls short. On the other hand side id(x) returns the id of the object.
I thought about creating a list and saving the bikes names/ids to a list and access them like that but i will run into the same problem that i cant access the instance by using a string. (I might be wrong on this)

Use a dict of Bycicle instances.

Why not just use a dict with the 2 inputs in a tuple as key {("red", "home"): <object of Bycicle>}, and then, once you get the 2 inputs, invoke the drive_to() of that object?

It is very unclear what you are trying to do. The only way you can map a string to an object is via a dict. So your code should be like : mydict = {"fast_bycicle":Bycicle("red", "home")} mydict[x].drive_to(y)

Awesome! Thanks a lot, i managed to access the object by using a dictionary as you suggested.
